# LazyException in web service EJB

Tags: web-services, ejb

sorry for my bad english..

my model:

```
public class Dog {

    private Integer id;
    private String mame;
    private List<Dog> childs; // lazy

}
```

my web service:

```
@WebService
public class DogWS {

    @EJB
    private DogRepository dogs

    public Dog get(String id){
        return dogs.get(id); // lazy exception
    }

}
```

when i make and search with SOAPui tool.. i receive an Exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

how to make and 'servlet filter' or similar in this case?

Comment: DogRepository code could be helpful, but the most probable scenario is: you loaded dog by id, your transaction has been closed, the dog entity became detached and now you are accessing a dog's child (for instance during SOAP message creation). If you do not want to make the childs property EAGER, you may access it before the dog object becomes detached. Like dogs.getChilds().size(). With this dog's children would be loaded and it would prevent further LazyInitializationException. PS. it's better to rename childs to children

Comment: call size method works fine :D, thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with accessing lazy collection after a dog object has been detached.

`dogs.getChilds().size()` method call before dog object was detached should solve the problem